# Using BCH/Zassenhaus formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been studying the problem of powers of a sum of matrices, for instance $(A+B)^t$. My initial thought was on approximating this as $A^t + B^t$, with the constraint in mind that $A$ and $B$ must be "close" in some sense. Looking at the Zassenhaus formula, I wonder if I can rewrite my problem as
$\exp(t(A+B))=\exp(tA)\exp(tB) \prod_{k=1}^\infty \exp(tC_k)$, where $C_k$ is a homogeneous polynomial of order $k$, always containing $[A,B]$.

If it is valid to take the $\log$ on either side, may we say
$(A+B)^t = A^t + B^t + \mathcal{O}([A,B])$?
If not, what could we say for the remaining error when truncating the series?

Comment: Even for commuting objects $(A+B)^t$ is very far from $A^t + B^t$

Comment: @user619894 In my case of substochastic matrices, I have found that it is actually a fair approximation at times, and I am wondering how to quantify to what extent that may be

Comment: What is the ballpark value of $t$?

Comment: @user619894 Very large, integer values, for $t$ are typical

Answer (score 2):

Find a similarity matrix $S$ such that $A+B = SDS^{-1}$, then $(A+B)^t = S  D^t S^{-1}$. Note that $D$ is composed of Jordan blocks, so that raising to a power is not too difficult.

Comment: Good idea, but finding these $S$ and $D$ may be just as difficult as diagonalizing the sum $A+B$. (In fact, all I really care about is the dominant eigenspace which I'd like to derive from the individual matrices.)  But thank you!

Comment: If the sum is diagonalizable, you are done. I don't know what "dominant eigenspace" is, but obviously the largest e.v. in absolute value will dominant for large $t$.

Comment: Surely, but I'm curious in how the corresponding eigenvectors behave (in the large $t$ limit), and additionally, how can we bound/estimate on the error in those statements? Does that make any sense?

Comment: The eigenvectors are the same for all powers

Comment: Yes but how do they relate to the eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Can't say much about the relation to $A,B$ individually without knowing something about them. Any matrix $M$ can be split into $M=A+(M-A)$. You wrote that $A,B$ are "close", So approximately $(A+B)^t \approx 2^t (A)^t$.